# Transform rectangle from decimal degrees to Cartesian coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, affine-transformation

I'm trying to achieve the following:
[image]

Given four coordinates (lat, lng) decimal degrees and a query coordinate within the formed shape, how can I transform these coordinates into Cartesian space where ideally, one of the corner points is the origin and the top right is (100, 100) and they form a rectangle? Also, how would I then get the coordinates of the query point?

I've found various programming language specific libraries that do transformations like these in Cartesian space between two shapes, but I'd be interested in a method to determine this without any specific programming language libraries that also takes the fact into account that I'm starting in decimal degrees.

Any hints?

Comment: `Given four coordinates (lat, lng) in EPSG:3857` EPSG:3857 doesn't use lat long coordinates

Comment: Pay attention to the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) and check thise article [Converting from longitude\latitude to Cartesian coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates), where you find `x = R * cos(lat) * cos(lon)` and `y = R * cos(lat) * sin(lon)`

Comment: @nmtoken Apologies if I'm using the wrong terminology. I just mean lat, lng pairs. I guess the projection doesn't matter?

Comment: @Taras Thanks! So that would convert them into cartesian space. Any hints at how to transform the result afterwards?

Comment: Let's start with software/tools/libraries you have access to. Afterwards it would be good knowing what kind of output would you like to achieve, e.g. a table or a graphic etc. Moreover, what are your skills in using a software with GUI or programming etc. Or perhaps you would like to perform this task manually with pen&pencil.

Comment: @Taras I've got a HTML table that represents a grid structure on the globe somewhere. I'd like to visually place a circle hovering over that table that reflects the users position within the grid. Since the physical grid can be oriented in any possible way and isn't necessarily going to be exactly right-angled, I would like to do this transformation to plot the users position on top of the HTML table. I'm going to be using javascript for the calculation and ideally wouldn't want to include any libraries as this seems like a basic mathematical problem.

Comment: @Taras Although now that I know what to search for, there seems to be a javascript library that does what I need once the coordinates have been converted into the cartesian system: https://github.com/jlouthan/perspective-transform

Comment: Please [Edit] the question without the assumption that Web Mercator is in units of decimal degrees. Also be sure that there is only One question per Question.