# Converting polygon with latitude and longitude to x y plane

Tags: coordinate-system, polygon, latitude-longitude, xy

I have a polygon (shape of a building) containing coordinates as latitude and longitude. I need to convert them into an x-y plane. I have used various methods such as:

```
const R = 6.371;
const x = R * Math.cos(lat) * Math.cos(lon);
const y = R * Math.cos(lat) * Math.sin(lon);
```

However, all methods do not scale up the coordinates in the x-y plane. The result ends up being a tremendously tiny polygon.

Comment: I am a bit at a loss what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Have you seen this topic [Transform rectangle from decimal degrees to Cartesian coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372046/transform-rectangle-from-decimal-degrees-to-cartesian-coordinates)?

Comment: Maybe you should use 6371 instead of 6.371!

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Most computer math functions take parameters in units of radians.

Comment: Use 6371000 so the results are in meters.